# Useful tools for working with Subversion

Tags: svn

There are a number of great tools out there which integrate with Subversion and do some really neat things. I’ve tried a number of them but ultimately only tend to use the following on a regular basis:

1. [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org) (the ubiquitous Explorer plugin)
2. [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn) (IDE integration for VS)
3. [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server) (light weight SVN server)
4. [SVN Monitor](http://www.svnmonitor.com) (repository monitoring)

What else is out there that you find really innovative or useful for interacting with Subversion?

Comment: I had never seen SVN Monitor until you mentioned it. Nice!

Comment: +1 on svn monitor.  essential for project leads or developers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In  addition to some previous comments:

- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) has excellent support for Subversion in terms of build tools other than CC.NEt and Hudson.
- [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) with Visual Studio (it's latest builds look quite nice)
- [Fisheye from Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) is an awesome way to monitor and view your source code/history/revisions with some neat statistics and support for code reviews, etc.

Answer (score 14):

[StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) is a really cool, albeit someone nerdy, tool for reporting details about your repo and commit statistics; it's really just graph porn :)

[Here](http://www.statsvn.org/statsvn/index.html) are some examples of the graphs.

Answer (score 7):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a issue tracker with SVN integration. I really like the *timeline view*, where one can quickly see all the *changesets* for quick code reviews.

Answer (score 7):

When writing or editing text in Microsoft Office, I stay focused on my
task. Like most of people, I feel disturbed when I have to interrupt my work for
some maintenance. Nevertheless, keeping document's change history under Subversion
can be considered a good practice.

For comparison, one must make as many as *5 steps* in order to **update a document** *via TortoiseSVN*:

1. close the document;
2. open its folder in Windows Explorer;
3. execute an Update command via context menu,
4. wait for its completion, close TortoiseSVN window,
5. open the document again.

I can reduce all these steps to just one click by using **[MagnetSVN](http://magnetsvn.com)** add-in for Microsoft Office.
 
**It is a real time saver!**
[image: MagnetSVN Ribbon Tab]

Comment: Please [disclose your affiliation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) when you recommend your products here.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, I like [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/). Other people prefer [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/). Both are nice SVN clients with excellent UI.

Answer (score 3):

I just end up using [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) just to stay in my IDE.

Answer (score 2):

the [svn protocol handler](http://tortoisesvn.net/SVNProtocolHandler) is also quite useful: it allows you to browse svn:// repositories in internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Commit Monitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor) to get notified of commits made by other devs.

I'll have to take a look at SVN Monitor, looks like it does the same thing, but has more features than Commit Monitor.

Comment: Yeah, CM is okay, but I ended up just putting in a post-commit hook to send emails instead.  Saves having yet another program on my computer, and saves the server being polled all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Synchro on Windows and Mac.  It works well especially if you have developers on different platforms.  I think that the license allows you a single user to use it on multiple platforms (I do full time development on Mac and test on Linux and Windows).

Versions is a Mac client with a nice UI.

Answer (score 1):

I use [kdesvn](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/) as a linux client, does the job.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the [hook scripts](http://subversion.tigris.org/tools_contrib.html#hook_scripts) that are available are quite useful to set up on your repository.  For instance I use a pre-commit hook to ensure a minimum log message length (some of our devs were prone to committing with an empty log message) and a post-commit hook to send an email to a mailing list.

I also think [RepoGuard](http://repoguard.tigris.org/) looks pretty interesting, but haven't had a chance to use it yet.

Answer (score 1):

SVNPlot generate cool statistics from your Subversion repository

Comment: SVNPlot - http://code.google.com/p/svnplot

Answer (score 1):

[Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) is a fairly nice Diff tool that integrates well with tortoise svn. I like it better than the default diff tool that comes with tortoise.

Answer (score 1):

[SvnQuery](http://svnquery.tigris.org/) is very useful if you need to search the contents of a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Coupling integration servers with version control does wonders to your build process. Two of my favorites are [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) - but there's lots out there. Note that both of these work seamlessly with SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of subversion web access apps. You can find an comparison here:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115215835/http://geekswithblogs.net/flanakin/articles/CompareSubversionWebTools.aspx)

Comment: Thats a pretty old comparison :)

Answer (score 0):

I really like [SyncroSVN](http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/) (I'm using it on a Mac)  Easy to use, built in dif and SSH support.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter D and Gabriel Florit; in Eclipse you get a gui and you can easily move around in the svn repository, deleting or renaming or whatever.  And with Hudson I have it check out my projects and build them and run their unit tests.

I haven't really explored it, but Maven has plugins for subversion.  I use Maven for building and deploying but haven't used it with the subversion plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a normal Subversion commandline client (e.g. from [SlikSvn](http://sliksvn.com/en/download)). By far the easiest way to script and/or automate subversion commands.

And maybe [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.net/) if you need more scripting power or when you would like to integrate Subversion support in your own .Net application. (AnkhSVN, Svn Monitor and several other tools are built on top of the SharpSvn binding).

Answer (score 0):

[commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/tagged/35/svn/sort-by-votes) made my life easier, I needed some weird stats out, just install cygwin if you're on Windows.